# errow when calculating geometric means

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the geometric means of some bird data for further analysis.

I have grouped the data under `common_name` and `observation_date`, with this code:

```
library(dplyr)
G_frame <- four %>%
     group_by(common_name, observation_date) %>%
     summarise(Population = log10(mean(log(observation_count))),
               sd.value = log10(sd(log(observation_count))), 
               count = n(),
               se.value = sd.value/sqrt(count))
```

it returns this error:

> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'common_name' (override with `.groups` argument)
> There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

and the output does not change

Reproducible code:

```
structure(list(protocol_type = c("Traveling", "Traveling", "Incidental", 
"Incidental", "Incidental", "Incidental"), common_name = c("Bachman's Sparrow", 
"Bachman's Sparrow", "Bachman's Sparrow", "Bachman's Sparrow", 
"Bachman's Sparrow", "Bachman's Sparrow"), observation_count = c(1, 
1, 0.5, 2, 2, 0.5), observation_date = structure(c(18004, 18363, 
11796, 13331, 13636, 13698), class = "Date"), bcr_code = c(27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    protocol_type = c("Incidental", "Traveling"), .rows = structure(list(
        3:6, 1:2), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: It looks like you might have some `NA`s in your data. Anywhere you use `mean()`, remember to include `mean(.., na.rm = TRUE)`, _if appropriate_ .

Comment: It returns a data.frame when inputting what you mentioned, however, the output in the `data.frame` has `NaN`, `-inf` and `NA` values along with some means

Comment: The warning you receive is because your data frame is already grouped (by `protocol_type`); it warns you that it is regrouping it. To prevent this warning, you can first `ungroup()` your data frame. The `NA` values occur because you take the `log10()` of the `log()` of `observation_count`. Since `observation_count` is often small, its `log` is negative, and the `log10` of a negative number does not exist, hence giving `NA`. Are you sure you need both `log`s?

Comment: @Bas I used `exp` instead of log10 and it seems to work better, I also converted the date into a single year, as that also had an impact. I imitated this link for geometric means: https://statisticsglobe.com/geometric-mean-in-r

Comment: On a side-note, is there a way to run this code with the observation dates as they are, so `2000-01-01`, rather than by a single year?